# TinyMCE auto_focus not working

Tags: codeigniter, tinymce

Im using TinyMCE for a replying mail form. The cursor should automatically land in the text entry. I used auto_focus:true but it would not work. Plz help.

My codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea.tmce",
    theme: "modern",
    auto_focus:true,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ],
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use something like this

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
          ed.focus();
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: <pre><code>
well thanks Thariama for your answer. well, in fact it worked with the line: 

tinymce.init({
....
auto_focus: "id_of_textarea",
....
</code></pre>

Answer (score 1):

There seems not to be way to disable the default auto focus. The workaround I found out, was to hook in the `init_instance_callback` option.

Something like:

```
tinymce({
    ...,
    init_instance_callback: () => {
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            document.querySelector('#myInput').focus();
        }, 0)
    }
})
```

I added `setTimeout(cb, 0)` just to ensure the callback is executed after the `init_instance_callback`

Answer (score 0):

The auto_focus property should contain the ID of the item that you want to focus on.

> [auto_focus](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aauto_focus): This option enables you to auto focus an editor instance. The value of
>   this option should be an editor instance id. The editor instance id is
>   the id for the original textarea or div element that got replaced.

I have actually seen IE7+ throw js errors if you had auto_focus set to true and not the ID of the textarea or div.

Comment: Looks like auto_focus : true is checked for in the code, and sets the editor correctly.  For me, the elementID didn't work as documented.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the execCommand point mentioned above, that is expected as if you're running a command then you're normally trying to edit content. You can disable this however by setting the skip_focus: true property in the args passed to execCommand. eg: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Gxgaab/1